# I'm have problem to import folder in reactjs. Actually I tried (import Boot from "./Bootstrap/Boot" to import on index.js ) . But its not working

Tags: html, reactjs, directory

I'm new in react js.
[Here I tried to import bootstrap folder in index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0uIo.png)

[But this error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFdl6.png)
[This is boot file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YWdY.png)

Comment: maybe try: import {Boot } from ". / Bootstrap/Boot". Or maybe you have not configured the export of the Boot.jsx file

Comment: I tried it before, but the same issue occurred.

Comment: In `Boot.jsx`, there is no need to `import ../Bootstrap`, remove that line and it will work